# VS Code too many changes in repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I created a new folder for the project, opened the IDE and I see that it reports too many changes. But this is a new project, why is she tracking the old one? Moreover, judging by source control, it looks at all the files in general and it is even unclear for what reason.

Tell me how to remove all this? Screenshot of the screen below

[image: Screenshot of VisualStudio Code]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Comment: There are 2 possibilities and with the information you gave, we can't be sure: 1. You have created the repo in the wrong folder (your user folder it seems and so deleting the '.git' folder should solve your problem) 2. You want to have your repo here but you need to ignore files and folders you don't want to track.